# Links in comments

Tags: android, eclipse, hyperlink

I just started creating an application and selected the navigation drawer option for the primary Activity because I felt lazy and didn't want to bother creating one myself. I noticed that there are links to methods etc.

```
{@link #restoreActionBar()}
```

How do I get these work in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+Click the link and it will send you where it should.

To create your own -

```
/** {@link #mymethodname()} */
```